# How to get value of the firs child inside the div using Jquery by the <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the div:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" value="1">Try1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" value="2">Try2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" value="3">Try3</a>
    <div>
```

And here is Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dropdown-menu div:first-child").attr("value");

    animalidd = $(this).attr("value");


aler(animalidd);

});
```

I just need the value of the first child that is selected automatically also after refresh and no i need it with `<div>` and `<a>`

Comment: You need the first anchor in the dropdown-menu div ?

Comment: @AndréDS yes beacuse my code in jquery don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the following selector : "div.dropdown-menu a:first-child"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var animalid = $("div.dropdown-menu a:first-child").attr("value");

     alert(animalid);

});
```

Here is a working example : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/vpamGm

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to make my answer as "solution". It may help other people